# Search for one value in a row and then few other values in the same row

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, vlookup

I have SheetA and SheetB in Google Spreadsheets.

I'm trying to write a formula that would be for example in Cell B2 of SheetA and would check if corresponding data is entered in SheetB and display person's name from row with corresponding date in cell B2 of SheetA.

It would repeat on other cells, of course, cell B2 is just for example.

So my basic problem is how to make a function that would search following in SheetB: Particular Date in B, and then Name in A and Task in C on the same row as the Particular Date

I hope I'm clear enough.

I've looked into IFS, LOOKUP, MATCH functions but I can't connect the dots and come up with the solution. :(

**SheetA**

[image: SheetA]

**SheetB**

[image: SheetB]

Comment: Index() with match() twice, but excel may be different to googlesheets so you need to know which you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in B2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A10&B1:E1, {SheetB!B:B&SheetB!C:C, SheetB!A:A}, 2, 0)))
```

---

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A10&B1:E1; {SheetB!B:B&SheetB!C:C\ SheetB!A:A}; 2; 0)))
```

Comment: Hm, it gives me Error VLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range. and #REF! in cells in SheetA. I tried changing the formula a bit but no luck so far. =INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A10&B1:E1; {SheetB!B2:B3&SheetB!C2:C3; SheetB!A2:A3}; 2; 0)))

Comment: @MountainSpring thats incorrect syntax. use 2nd fx from answer

Comment: @MountainSpring maybe: `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A10&B1:E1; FILTER({SheetB!B:B&SheetB!C:C\ SheetB!A:A}; SheetB!D:D=TRUE); 2; 0)))`

Comment: Works, thank you so much. :)
In the meantime I tried this:
=IF(SheetB!D2 = TRUE ; (INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2&B1:E1; {SheetB!B:B&SheetB!C:C\ SheetB!A:A}; 2; 0)))) ; " ")

It also works but I would have to put it on each line of B column of SheetA, your suggestion is much better, thanks.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to expand this a little bit so that FILTER searches all the same things but in SheetC as well (which is of the same structure as SheetB).
Tried to play with something like this, but no luck :(
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A10&B1:E1; FILTER({SheetB!B:B&SheetB!C:C\ SheetB!A:A}; SheetB!D:D=TRUE)+FILTER({SheetC!B:B&SheetC!C:C\ SheetC!A:A}; SheetC!D:D=TRUE) ; 2; 0)))

Comment: @MountainSpring try: `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A10&B1:E1; 
{FILTER({SheetB!B:B&SheetB!C:C\ SheetB!A:A}; SheetB!D:D=TRUE);
FILTER({SheetC!B:B&SheetC!C:C\ SheetC!A:A}; SheetC!D:D=TRUE)} ; 2; 0)))`